# Abstract type members in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, scala, generics, type-members

I love *Scala*'s abstract type members, which is a great feature.

For example, consider this simple example, as entered into the Scala REPL:

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

/** Base class for a pet food class.
 */
abstract class PetFood

/** Dog food.
 */
final class DogFood extends PetFood

/** Cat food.
 */
final class CatFood extends PetFood

/** An abstract Pet.
 */
abstract class Pet {

  /** Type of food this pet will eat.
   */
  type Food <: PetFood

  /** Eat some food.
   */
  final def eat(food: Food): Unit = println("Yum!")
}

/** A dog.
 */
final class Dog extends Pet {

  // Dogs require dog food.
  override type Food = DogFood
}

/** A cat.
 */
final class Cat extends Pet {

  // Cats require cat food.
  override type Food = CatFood
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class PetFood
defined class DogFood
defined class CatFood
defined class Pet
defined class Dog
defined class Cat

scala> val dog = new Dog
dog: Dog = Dog@2036f83

scala> dog.eat(new DogFood)
Yum!

scala> dog.eat(new CatFood)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : CatFood
 required: dog.Food
    (which expands to)  DogFood
       dog.eat(new CatFood)
               ^
```

Both `Dog` and `Cat` are still types of `Pet`, and can be used wherever a `Pet` is required, but they have specific food requirements. But the key point is that `Pet` is still polymorphic.

I'm trying to do something similar in *C#* (in version 7.2), but—so far as I can tell—it appears not to support the concept of abstract type members (or even just type members).

What I'd like to avoid doing is just making `Pet` generic, because that would destroy the polymorphism. For example:

```csharp
public abstract class PetFood {
}

public sealed class DogFood: PetFood {
}

public sealed class CatFood: PetFood {
}

public abstract class Pet<F>
where F: PetFood {

    public void Eat(F food) => Console.WriteLine("Yum!");
}

public sealed class Dog: Pet<DogFood> {
}

public sealed class Cat: Pet<CatFood> {
}
```

This works in terms of ensuring that pets eat the correct type of food, but `Pet` is no longer polymorphic (I can't pass a `Dog` or a `Cat` instance when a `Pet` instance is required, because I need a generic argument for `Pet` instances).

Is there a way to achieve this in *C#*? (Or an alternative *.NET* language?)

(My actual use case is a little more complex than this, but I'm trying to keep the explanation simple. Suffice to say, it's not sufficient to create a non-generic base class for the hierarchy.)

Answer (score 1):

What I do in situations like this is separate out the non-generic stuff into an abstract, non-generic class, Pet, and make Pet derived from it. It doesn't really make sense to polymorphically pass in a pet to a place that intends to call the Eat method.

You could also make all methods or types that use Pet generic but that doesn't help with collections.

Comment: As I stated, I can't use a non-generic base class. This is because, in my actual use case, the types are part of the required polymorphism. (I don't actually expose them in the same way that I indicate in the Pet Food example.) If it's not possible to do abstract types/path-dependent types in C# (or other .NET languages), then that's an acceptable answer, and I'll have to figure out a less elegant solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in .NET that does what you want. The best I can think of is to make the implementations of the Eat method do type checking and throw an exception if it is given the wrong type or to remove the abstract Eat method and only have it in the derived types. It's possible that covariance or contravariance can help but they only work on interfaces and I don't have much experience with them.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure about your goal, but maybe something like this helps:

```
public interface IFood<T>
{
    string Brand { get; }
}

public class Pet<T>
{
    public void Eat(IFood<T> food)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(food.Brand);
    }
}

public class DogFood : IFood<Dog>
{
    public string Brand => "Dog Deli";
}

public class CatFood : IFood<Cat>
{
    public string Brand => "Lucky Cat";
}

public class Dog : Pet<Dog> {}
public class Cat : Pet<Cat> {}

(new Dog()).Eat(new DogFood());
(new Cat()).Eat(new CatFood());
// (new Cat()).Eat(new DogFood()); <-- won't compile
```

Edit: add a class that accepts any Pet

```
public class PetChecker
{
    public void CheckPet<T>(Pet<T> pet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pet.GetType().Name);
    }
}
new PetChecker().CheckPet(new Dog()); // output: "Dog"
```

Comment: That works, from the perspective of ensuring dogs & cats eat the right kind of food, but there's no relationship between a `Dog` and a `Cat` in terms of being polymorphic versions of `Pet`. That is I can't have a method that expects a pointer to a `Pet` and will accept a `Dog` or a `Cat` instance; I have to make the method generic. In effect, `Dog`s and `Cat`s are now different types altogether. They have a common structure, but no polymorphism. I was looking for a way of implementing _abstract type members_ or _path-dependent types_ in _C#_, and it appears that's not possible.

Comment: But is this much of a disadvantage? Look at the "PetChecker" in my edit. Of course "Pet" could be abstract and implement more interfaces which is how C# does (sort of a) polymorphism.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. Maybe my example is a poor one, or I phrased it badly. I am looking for a _C#_ equivalent of the _Scala_ code at the top of my question, that (ideally) works in the same way. The objective is _not_ to have pets eat the right kind of food (in your example, both the food _and_ the pets are non-polymorphic, by comparison to my _C#_ example, which is moving even further away from what I want), but to have abstract types—a type that is a member of the class, and that can be modified by sub-classes.

Comment: Note that the _Scala_ version does not use generics. Instead, it makes `Food` a type member of `Pet` (which is inherited by both `Cat` & `Dog`), and defines a constraint on it (`Food` must be a sub-class of `PetFood`). Both `Cat` & `Dog` can then further constrain that type (it's abstract, right?) so that it meets their needs better. But, critically, both `Dog` and `Cat` are still `Pet`s. In your example, a `Dog` is a `Pet<Dog>` and a `Cat` is a `Pet<Cat>` and there's no relationship between them other than shared code. Anything that accepts a `Pet` has to be generic, so it's not polymorphic.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the generic CheckPet method in the PetChecker. Yes, it needs the generic type parameter, but that does not make a difference for the method argument, you still just pass a Dog. Also, why are Cats and Dogs not Pets? They inherit from Pet with all the goodies that comes with that. As for the additional constraint - I don't fully understand but that may be a disadvantage of the approach. It may not work exactly as it does in Scala but I am questioning if this is a problem with actual, practical requirements.

Comment: The problem is that any other class that needs a reference to a `Pet` needs to be generic, so that the actual type of `Pet` can be specified. In my real-world case, I have a number of class hierarchies similar to `Pet`, and they reference each other. If type `A` needs a reference to type `B`, then that's simple. But if `B` is generic, then `A` needs to be too. So I would need an `A<T>` to reference a `B<T>`. If `A` also needs to reference a generic `C` object, then I need another type parameter, so that `A<T1, T2>` can reference a `B<T1>` and a `C<T2>`, and so it proliferates.